# Maven + GWT: Use Source Files from API(non GWT) project

Tags: java, maven, gwt, dto

I have a sample project which is seperated into smaller projects: api, impl, service and different UI projects. The UI projects talk with the service project. It should be a loose coupling of the ui. I started to implement a UI project with GWT and want to use a DTO from the API project. I added the sources to the jar via maven resources, but the GWT project still cant find the DTO source file during GWT compilation.
The dependecy hierachy is:

api-project <- gwt-module-project <- gwt-application-project

the module part is implementing own widgets and logic and the application project aggregates different modules into an application.

How can I achieve to get access of the DTO source file?

Comment: Those dependency arrows would make more sense facing the other direction.  What is the packaging type of your gwt-module-project?  If it is a jar have you tried including api-project in the gtw-module-project's pom as a Maven dependency?

Comment: I changed the arrows direction. The packaging of the gwt-module-project ist jar. The api-project is added as a maven dependency. The problem is, that the gwt compiler does not find source files which are not in a package listed with <source path='relativePackageName'/>

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this ain't possible (I'm in the exact same position). According to http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/PathsHandlingFAQ you need to have a .gwt.xml file in each module that the GWT compiler should consider.
I'd also happily accept input for work-arounds.